# Guest SSID on secondary (WAP extension) router

Tags: router, wifi

Current setup:

```
ONU/Modem --> Router 1 (Main) --> Router 2 (Extension)

* R1 - TomatoUSB firmware (3.4-140 USB AIO-64K)  
* R2 - DD-WRT firmware (v24-sp2)
- R2 set up as Wireless Access Point (connected to R1 LAN-LAN)
- R2 DHCP server disabled
```

I'd like to have a separate subnet for Guest SSID so guests won't have access to home computers.

I know it's possible to setup on R1, but will it work on R2 since its DHCP server is disabled and gets IP address leases on R1?